# Why does Infinity passed to interval does not wait forever in Rx.js?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Can someone please explain me why the following snippet immediately outputs digits 0 to 6 ?

```
 Rx.Observable.interval(1/0).take(6).forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

> Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: It's probably because `Infinity` is `0` when coerced to an integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from [the source code of RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) that `Observable.interval` expects (and uses) its input as an integer:

```
module Rx {
    export interface ObservableStatic {
        /**
         *  Returns an observable sequence that produces a value after each period.
         *
         * @example
         *  1 - res = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
         *  2 - res = Rx.Observable.interval(1000, Rx.Scheduler.timeout);
         *
         * @param {Number} period Period for producing the values in the resulting sequence (specified as an integer denoting milliseconds).
         * @param {Scheduler} [scheduler] Scheduler to run the timer on. If not specified, Rx.Scheduler.timeout is used.
         * @returns {Observable} An observable sequence that produces a value after each period.
         */
        interval(period: number, scheduler?: IScheduler): Observable<number>;
    }
}
```

and since in Javascript

```
(1/0) === Infinity
```

and `Infinity` is zero when turned into an integer:

```
(Infinity | 0) === 0
```